# How to replace a value in web.xml with a Maven property?

Tags: maven, servlets, parameters, web.xml

I have a Maven project that downloads some test files into its build directory `./target/files`. These files should then be available to a servlet, which I can easily achieve by hardcoding the full path as an `<init-param>` of the servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>filepath</param-name>
        <param-value>/home/user/testproject/target/files</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

How can I avoid hardcoding the full path and use a dynamic parameter replacement instead? I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
<param-value>${project.build.directory}/files</param-value>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how your project downloads the test files? What triggers that? Normally problems like this are solved by enabling filtering, but it may be difficult depending upon how these files appear.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Add to your pom section:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See [Maven: Customize web.xml of web-app project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15006170/651140) for more details

Comment: See also https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html for more info

Comment: What's in the solution that enables the replacement?

Comment: @alikelzin-kilaka: you can define a property in your pom.xml (e.g. "<myProp>Moin</myProp>") and if you have in your web.xml a placeholder ("${myProp}") this will be replaced with the value of your property (with "Moin" in my sample)

Comment: This one is actually replacing the placeholder with actual value from the pom property, but after deploying its  giving error saying -- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.to.active' in string value "${spring.profiles.to.active}". Whereas in .war and inside target folder its the new value. Any idea why its happening so?

Comment: @JohnMaclein I am having the same issue. It seems that all the found files are copied to the "warSourceDirectory". That means that the web.xml will be placed into the root folder. However: The <webXml> tag is reading from the original WEB-INF folder where the property isn't replaced. Try "<webXml>src/main/webapp/web.xml</webXml>"

Comment: I believe that <filtering>true</filtering> is what does the trick of variable replacement

Comment: copy/paste, this solution worked perfectly. Now I was able to make a context param dependent on ${environment}

Comment: @daPhantom actually you should not specify the <webXml> tag at all to make it work with m2e-wtp (deploying to servers from Eclipse). see https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBIDE-16341 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487370#c13

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use maven [filtering resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html):

```
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

You can also combine this and would like to filter some files whereas others shouldn't be filtered:

```
   <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
```

Put appropriate placeholders into the files you would like having replaced things like ${home}.

Comment: This code does filters and replace strings in XML files with the values defined in the pom.xml <properties> tag or do I need to use a properties file?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Replace Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) to do it.

Heres a sample Implementation where i replace the tokenkeys in a property file , adapt it to suit your needs

**test.properties**

```
SERVER_NAME=@SERVER_NAME@
PROFILE_NAME=@PROFILE_NAME@
```

**pom.xml**

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>

            <replace dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources" >
              <include name="**/*.properties"/>
             <replacefilter     token="@SERVER_NAME@" value="My Server"/>
             <replacefilter     token="@PROFILE_NAME@" value="My Profile"/>
            </replace>             

          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

voila!
**Now execute**

```
mvn clean package
```

Comment: Better use [resources filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) instead of Ant.

Comment: While the accepted answer is better for the actual question asked, this is actually exactly what I was looking for so I could replace versions for webjar dependencies in static html files. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use maven-war-plugin's filteringDeploymentDescriptors option to filter deployment descriptors -

```
<properties>
    <maven.war.filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</maven.war.filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `maven-war-plugin` and set `<filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>` to replace the placeholder when running `mvn package`

```
<properties>
  <project.build.directory>your path</project.build.directory>
</properties>

<build>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coding maven parameters in web.xml can't work directly, because at run time, when your application starts, maven has finished its work and the application has no knowledge about maven.

You can filter an alternative web.xml (see maven filtering: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) and use it when building the war (see the webXml parameter at the war plugin documentation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html)