# Maven EAR Plugin - export 3 files at time

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ear, maven-ear-plugin

First of all - sorry for my poor english :P I'm decided to write because I searched all google and stackoverflow and I didn't find answer...

So, I have a maven project in eclipse (Windows) and I have to export three packages (each time with another web.xml). And my question is: Is it possible to change dynamically web.xml (in WEB-INF) during maven installing/building project and as a result get 3 ear files, each of them build for another web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the maven-war plugin to manipulate your web.xml.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355708/how-to-replace-a-value-in-web-xml-with-a-maven-property)  can maybe help.