# How to create maven profile based variables for use in web.xml with maven-ear-plugin

Tags: jsf-2, maven-3, web.xml, maven-profiles, maven-ear-plugin

I wish to do something similar to this question: [How to replace a value in web.xml with a Maven property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15355708/637609) and similar to this [web article](http://www.iliachemodanov.ru/en/blog-en/11-java/jsf/32-jsf-project-stage-en)

I want to add the JSFProjectStage to the web.xml of my 3 (war) subprojects using a variable based on the maven profile.

I do not use the maven-war-plugin. I am using the maven-ear-plugin. Is there a way to do this using the maven-ear-plugin?

Comment: If you have war project why not using maven-war-plugin...does not make sense? Can you show your pom files and what you tried?

Comment: I have 3 war projects which are packaged into an ear using the maven-ear plugin. I have tried adding the property to the profile, but then I realised I needed the maven-war-plugin configuration.