# How to replace property placeholder in web.xml with a value from pom.xml

Tags: xml, spring, pom.xml, web.xml, maven-war-plugin

I have a web.xml in which I intend to replace a property placeholder with a value from pom.xml. But after reading stack overflow's [How to replace a value in web.xml with a Maven property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355708/how-to-replace-a-value-in-web-xml-with-a-maven-property) question I implemented the it in the following way.

Now my web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>${spring.profiles.to.active}</param-value>
    </context-param>

    ...
    ...
</web-app>
```

And my pom.xml's build part looks like this

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```

After all these changes when I run the application using *mvn package*, its performing what it intends to do, i.e. its actually replacing the placeholder with the intended value and the updated web.xml is present in the *target* directory.

So now my new web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    ...
    ...
</web-app>
```

But now the interesting part comes. When I am going to deploy it in either tomcat or in Pivotal Tc server, its giving me this weird error

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 511 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.to.active' in string value "${spring.profiles.to.active}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:158)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:87)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:465)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.doGetActiveProfiles(AbstractEnvironment.java:241)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getActiveProfiles(AbstractEnvironment.java:228)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.merge(AbstractEnvironment.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.setParent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3831)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Or Does anyone have the solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you read the stacktrace? `spring.profiles.to.active` != `spring.profiles.to.active` . It isn't complaining about the `web.xml` but you are using the same placeholder in your configuration somewhere which isn't being replaced. (Note I really think you shouldn't be using profiles like this as it means you are building artifacts per environment and which means you are putting untested artifacts into production!).

Comment: Nope its not the case cause in my war file I explored the web.xml and there its perfectly replacing the "${spring.profiles.to.active}" value with "development" and there is no other occurrences of spring.profiles.to.active. Also could you suggest me any better way for environment driven development with spring web mvc not with spring boot.

Comment: It must be somewhere else in your xml files or `@Value` annotations as that is the only thing that the placeholder configurer scans. It doesn't do anything with the `web.xml`.