# How to replace web.xml during build with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, replace, web.xml

I have a problem with maven. i'm alredy using tomcat7-maven-plugin to deploy my war into a tomcat and it works great.

But now I would like to change a file into my generated war before to send it to servlet container. Is it possible?
Particularly I want to change default web.xml with another one.

I've already tried a maven-resources-plugin as showed below:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>default-copy-resources</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}/WEB-INF/</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/ext/WEB-INF</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but this plugin replace web.xml just on target WEB-INF folder, nothing will be changed into war file.
Someone can help me to find the right plugin to achive my purpose?

> UPDATE:

I resolved using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298876/2148530

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve? If you want to use a (possibly faulty) web.xml you can always put it in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` in the standard directory layout.

Comment: Do you want to change it for specific builds only? That can be done using maven profiles. But what do you want to achieve? To change the whole web.xml or have some of their attributes with different values?

Comment: I've already have a `web.xml` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` but i would replace it with another one during build and deploy.

Comment: Consider that the right phase it isn't package but `tomcat7:deploy`. So when I launch `mvn tomcat7:deploy`. I would like to change web.xml. But your second option could be ok. The replacing `web.xml` is similar to original one, it is slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your profile(in your pom.xml) within it you override the **maven.war.webxml** property   :

```
<properties>
    <maven.war.webxml>path/to/your/custom/web.xml</maven.war.webxml>
</properties>
```

Comment: This solution is very powerful when combined with maven profiles. In that way, it is possible to define one different web.xml for each profile.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (not mine), taken from question [Maven: Customize web.xml of web-app project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298763/maven-customize-web-xml-of-web-app-project) with [Maven War Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) and `webXml` parameter.

> **webXml** The path to the web.xml file to use.

### Sample usage

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>tomcat</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webXml>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/ext/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                 ...
```

Comment: Your command and your edit have no effect, furthermore at the end it returns:
 [WARNING] The requested profile "tomcat" could not be activated because it does not exist.

Comment: First of all create profile `tomcat` - http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html and put your resource plugin into it.

Comment: I resolved using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3298876/2148530. Thanks let me know profiles!

Comment: Profiles are very helpful :)

Comment: @giaffa86 I have replaced my answer with your solution.

Comment: @MariuszS could you check my question on my profile please