# How to set env entries for deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, wildfly, web.xml

I have a JavaEE application that communicates with other services via RESTful API. The hostname:port of remote services is set through environment entries (`<env-entry/>` in `web.xml`, not to confuse with environment variables!). This value is later obtained through field annotated with `@Resource`.

As the build process is isolated from deployment, I want to override the defaults in `web.xml` (where the variable is set to `localhost`) that ends up in `app.war` to actual hostname. I suppose this is done by providing another `web.xml` or `jboss-web.xml` (on WildFly) along with , but I can't find how this is set up; I guess this must be a simple process, not involving repackaging the `app.war`.

Comment: is this what you are looking for?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298763/maven-customize-web-xml-of-web-app-project

Comment: No, that tells you how to switch the contents of `app.war` through profile. I want single `app.war`, and configure the environment entry only during deployment (when the sources, and Maven are not available).

Comment: Actually I have never used this kind of config (prefering properties files), but it seems that this mechanism is using JNDI. Therefore, maybe this link maybe helpful: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JNDI+Reference

Comment: I read that document before, but I don't see how the local JNDI properties could be set (obviously, it's not in standalone.xml as this allows to set only global properties).

Answer (score 1):

You can use descriptor replacement property. Maybe these links can help you:

[Java EE Application Deployment and Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Java+EE+Application+Deployment+Configuration)

[Property substitution of deployment descriptor](https://blog.akquinet.de/2012/11/21/property-substitution-of-deployment-descriptor-in-eap6-and-jboss-as7/)

Comment: According to the second document, those properties allow to override only jboss-web.xml - is overriding web.xml allowed by default?

Comment: You can use jboss-web.xml, it can replace web.xml. So you should be able to achieve properties override. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+WildFly

Comment: That's not very handy, since the WAR shouldn't be tied to WildFly (adding jboss-web.xml kind of suggests that).